# URL path settings not supporting more than one level

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm trying to edit and create content on my inherited Drupal site and when I enter an address into the "URL Path Settings' URL Alias" field, it will not save the first part of the desired URL.
For example if I enter "firstpart/contentname"
it just saves "contentname" instead of the full hierarchy.

Comment: And are you sure your firstpart token is correct, and that the (Entity) Token module is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. If you edit the URL alias manually, it shouldn't be automatically changed unless you bulk delete and update your URL aliases in Pathauto.

Have you checked your Pathauto pattern settings (/admin/config/search/path/patterns) to see if there is something overriding your changes?

You said that you inherited the site. Are there any URL/path-related modules that your predecessor has enabled?